# Invalid certificate name on go,microsoft.com

Tags: tls, web-browser

About 1 times out of 20, going to go.microsoft.com displays this page:

[image]

The certificate is for www.holidaycheck.de which doesn't make sense. (Note: I'm Canadian, not Deutsch.)

The other 19 times, I go to the regular go.microsoft.com website with a correct certificate.

I did a little research and according to WHOIS IP, both go.microsoft.com and www.holidaycheck.de are handled by Akamai.

I'm trying to find an explanation of that weird behaviour. It only happens with Chrome for one of my computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The routing system in your region's Akamai server is malfunctioning.

After HSTS 307 redirect to the HTTPS site, the Akamai server seems to give your browser a wrong site that they serve.

It's their problem, as the certificate seems to be valid for the other site. If the certificate is gibberish, you might be under attack.

Interesting, though.

Comment: How do I know if the certificate is gibberish? And how would I test if I'm under attack?

Comment: @RainingChain in your case, the offending certificate is signed by a trusted certificate authority. If it were gibberish, this wouldn't be the case.